# Error while taking input from the user. NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, input, runtime, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter any two numbers: ");
int a,b,c;
a=sc.nextInt();
b=sc.nextInt();
c=a+b;
System.out.println("The sum = "+c);
}
}
```

[image]

I did the same program on VS Code - it ran without issue.

I used the following online IDEs:-

1. tutorialspoint.com (same error)
2. jdoodle.com (executed successfully)
3. onlinegdb.com (executed successfully)
4. programquiz.com (executed successfully)
5. online-java.com (executed successfully)
6. w3schools.com (same error)
7. interviewbit.com (same error)

I had to use an online IDE for my interview - I don't remember.

I have tried to understand the exception, but I cannot align my issue with what the exception is all about. I've read multiple stack overflow threads about this issue. Some people are saying, I should not use close() - but I haven't even used it! Others are giving solutions that are not related to my issue at all.

Please give me some directions or hint so that I can learn from this problem.

Comment: The exception simply states that the required input (two integers) that was supposed to be read, were not provided to `System.in`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, can you understand where I've done wrong in my program? This is extremely embarrassing :(

Comment: This issue is not about the program. It is about how you provide input to `System.in`. In your terminal, you do that manually by typing the values (your two integers) into the terminal. However in some online IDEs, you don't input that into the console, but rather in a seperate "Input" field/section, as shown by the answer below.

Comment: Oh my God!! Thank you so much! It all makes sense now. I panicked during the interview and forgot about providing inputs in a separate tab or something. I'm so dumb :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is more on how the IDE is written, may be it is not giving you an interactive screen to give an input and expects you to do that separately.

Just checked this for w3schools.com and interviewbit.com where we have a separate section for giving the input and this code runs perfectly fine there.

See both the screen shots attached
[image: input tab]

[image: W3Schools]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is an IDE issue? Please confirm. BTW, I just ran the code again on my Ubuntu terminal, it worked fine. It is unbelievable! This whimsical error just ruined my interview.

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I get it now. Thank you all. What a wonderful community :)